# Bad Controller/Model names in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

On my current RoR project I have a table that stores pdf's (using paperclip gem). I've named the model 'Document' and a controller called 'documents'. This gave me a lot of weird errors, and I think it's because Rails uses those names already somewhere. From there I wondered if there's a list somewhere with names you should avoid in Rails? Does anybody know if there's something like this on the web? My searches didn't pan out... Also, let me know if you think the name of the model/controller is not the problem at all, so I can do some other checks. Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document` word is probably a reserved one.

I found a long list of other reserved words [here](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords),

Answer (score 0):

There's an attempt at reviving the old Rails wiki reserved words page here:

https://github.com/walterdavis/railsready/wiki